# Multiple menu items highlighted

Tags: categories, menus, navigation, customization

I am using WordPress as the CMS for my website. For my navigation menu, I am using WordPress' inbuilt navigation menu function. You add categories, page, etc, to this and it generates a list with certain classes you can style - like `current-menu-item`.

My problem lies here:

- I have several categories in my menu, and some posts have to be assigned to multiple categories.
- If a post was for example in a `Category A` only, then when you are on the page with that post, `Category A` would be highlighted in the menu.
- If a post is in `Category A` and `Category B`, then when you are on the page with that post, `Category A` and `Category B` would both be highlighted.

How can I highlight only one menu item, even though the post is in multiple categories?

Answer (score 2):

This question was also asked [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557832/multiple-menu-items-highlighted-in-wordpress). Here's a copy of the answer i gave there:

Perhaps you could style it using the `nth-of-type` CSS3 selector.

```
.current-menu-item:nth-of-type(1) {
    background:#ffff00;
    /* Highlight styles */
}
```

These styles would target only the first occurrence of the .current-menu-item. Likewise, you could choose to target the second with `nth-of-type(2)`, et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and without a selected answer but I would like to elaborate and extend upon Thomas' response earlier. The nth-of-type selector is pretty well supported but older versions of IE < 9 don't support it.

My solution would be to use the more widely supported first-child selector instead.

```
.current-menu-item:first-child {
    background:#ffff00;
    /* Highlight styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It may be a hotlinking issue.**

You'll see from this site at http://www.wildpop.ca (Wildpop dot.ca), when you choose "SEO" from the menu, you are directed to what appears to be the "Monthly Packages" page. The SEO link in the menu does not have it's own page. It is a direct link to a section named (seo_direct) that is contained in a different page, but when you look at the menu again - both menu options are highlighted as "Active Page".

Make sure this isn't the issue for you.